# How to assign path variables to headers in a java dsl http inbound gateway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Hey i can't quite figure out how to convert this:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="eventSinkPayloadChannel"
                          path="/EventSink/{producer}/{consumer}"
                          supported-methods="POST" >
    <int-http:header name="PRODUCER" expression="#pathVariables.producer"/>
    <int-http:header name="CONSUMER" expression="#pathVariables.consumer"/>
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

into the Java DSL. I thought the `headerExpression` method would be the one to use,

```
        Http.inboundGateway("/EventSink/{producer}/{consumer}")
                      .headerExpression("PRODUCER", expression)
                      .headerExpression("CONSUMER", expression)
                      .get()
```

but i can't really pass a string in the second argument, coz it's expecting the type Expression, so i dunno if i have to instantiate a SpelExpression there or if i'm even using the right method actually.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static final SpelExpressionParser PARSER = new SpelExpressionParser();

...

    .headerExpression("PRODUCER", PARSER.parseExpression("#pathVariables.producer"))
```