# Spring Integration Java DSL - Http Outbound Gateway uri variable Expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-el

I have a Http Outbound Gateway where I want to set a uri variable with a value from a Message header. I can see that this can be done like so:

```
            .handle(Http
                    .outboundGateway(serviceUri, restTemplate)
                    .uriVariable("var", expression)
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
```

The expression is of type `org.springframework.expression.Expression`. How do I create such an `Expression` object for say a JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID value? I can't find any examples anywhere. I know that the String SPEL would be `"headers['correlationId']"` but I don't know how to turn that into an `Expression` object?

I am using `spring-integration-java-dsl:1.1.0.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587850/how-to-assign-path-variables-to-headers-in-a-java-dsl-http-inbound-gateway/33588333#33588333).

Note that `JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID` is actually `jms_correlationId`. It's safer to use the constant...

```
PARSER.parseExpression("headers['" + JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID + "']");
```

Comment: Thanks for that Gary. Yes, I am using the constant in `JmsHeaders`. In the end I had created the expression as a literal (`new LiteralExpression("headers['" + JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID + "']")`) which I assume is also valid?

Comment: No; that is not correct; a `LiteralExpression` is an, err, literal - i.e. it will set the variable to the exact literal in the constructor. `LiteralExpression`s are not evaluated, `getValue()` simply returns the value passed into the constructor. You need to parse the expression so it is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll use the expression as you have provided then Gary.